# Next.js 14 middleware - How to use auth middleware along with next-intl middle ware?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-intl

I'm working on a Next.js 14 project in which i'm using next-intl for localization, Also i have added auth function in middleware.ts to protect route along with next-intl middleware. Everything works fine when its default language, but when local is changed and language code is added to url, app is giving error "Too many redirects" and it crashes.

Please find the below code for your reference and help to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

```
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { localePrefix, locales } from "./navigation";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const token = req.cookies.get("tbt")?.value;
  const isProtectedRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/app");

  if (!token && isProtectedRoute) {
    const absoluteURL = new URL("/login", req.nextUrl.origin);
    return NextResponse.redirect(absoluteURL.toString());
  }
  if (token && !isProtectedRoute) {
    const absoluteURL = new URL("/app/explore", req.nextUrl.origin);
   return NextResponse.redirect(absoluteURL.toString());
  }

  return createMiddleware({
    locales,
    localePrefix,
    defaultLocale: "en",
  })(req);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
};
```